# Why does my Heroku API app not return json data?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I created a Node.js, Express, PostgreSQL API and hosted it on Heroku. After pushing it to Heroku, I am able to see the home page but when I go to the /colors route I don't get any data. Any help you can give me in figuring this problem out would help.

Here is a link to the [site](https://api-colors.herokuapp.com/) and [repo](https://github.com/sonAndrew/ColorsAPI).

Logs:

```
    2020-06-17T03:15:01.217602+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-06-17T03:15:02.439787+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2020-06-17T03:15:05.313847+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started on: 32495.
2020-06-17T03:15:05.784686+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-17T03:15:18.042530+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/colors" host=api-colors.herokuapp.com request_id=6196ed32-f423-4602-ad3d-ce126e91dfeb fwd="73.131.85.220" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=58ms status=500 bytes=744 protocol=https
2020-06-17T03:15:18.046053+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: self signed certificate
2020-06-17T03:15:18.046095+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1506:34)
2020-06-17T03:15:18.046096+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
2020-06-17T03:15:18.046096+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:948:8)
2020-06-17T03:15:18.046097+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:706:12)
2020-06-17T03:15:47.081186+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=api-colors.herokuapp.com request_id=3cc79d25-b300-4c65-a667-62ff18d75592 fwd="73.131.85.220" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=869 protocol=https
2020-06-17T03:16:30.773456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=api-colors.herokuapp.com request_id=89237876-0288-476e-8f3c-be1c8f692d10 fwd="73.131.85.220" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=592 protocol=https
2020-06-17T03:18:03.112837+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=api-colors.herokuapp.com request_id=eaf8785d-5f32-4aaf-a2e9-6077be7f9df5 fwd="73.131.85.220" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=592 protocol=https
2020-06-17T03:18:05.473221+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=api-colors.herokuapp.com request_id=e8ad5819-21d1-4779-aa8c-2a2e722913c8 fwd="73.131.85.220" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=592 protocol=https
2020-06-17T03:18:18.755366+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: self signed certificate
2020-06-17T03:18:18.755384+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1506:34)
2020-06-17T03:18:18.755385+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
2020-06-17T03:18:18.755385+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:948:8)
2020-06-17T03:18:18.755386+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:706:12)
2020-06-17T03:18:18.753356+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/colors" host=api-colors.herokuapp.com request_id=c8966ce9-76bf-4f67-abae-24008433c025 fwd="73.131.85.220" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=744 protocol=https
```

Comment: Have you checked your heroku logs, it says `Internal server error` on the `/colors` route currently

Comment: As mentioned, step one is to actually check the logs, either using the [heroku cli](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) log command, or by going to your app on herokuapp.com and in the upper right expanding the menu options and picking the logs option.

Comment: Well here are the logs. I says self signed certificate but not sure how to fix it. Looked online but couldn't find anything that would help.